# Mocking a method which is called using an arrow function as a parameter

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, arrow-functions, sinon-chai

How can I use the Sinon package to stub/mock a method call where one of the parameters I have to mock is called using an arrow function? eg

```
let objWithMethod = { method : function(x) {}; };
function SUT() {
    // use case
   let x = 'some value';
   let y = { anotherMethod : function(func) {}; };

   // I want to test that `y.anotherMethod()` is called with
   // `(x) => objWithMethod.method(x)` as the argument
   y.anotherMethod((x) => objWithMethod.method(x));
}

let mockObj = sinon.mock(objWithMethod);

// Both of these fail with a "never called" error
mockObj.expects('method').once().withArgs(objWithMethod.method.bind(this, x));
mockObj.expects('method').once().withArgs((x) => objWithMethod.method(x));

SUT();
mockObj.verify();
```

I couldn't find anything in the sinon docs nor after a few attempts at a google search.

Comment: You don't access `objWithMethod.method` in your code. `objWithMethod` is an object, while you call it as a function. How does it even work?

Comment: Your code causes `VM604:5 Uncaught TypeError: objWithMethod is not a function` (after you fix a problem with extra `;` in the first line)

Comment: you're right my example is not correctly representing what im asking i will update it

Comment: updated to reflect what i meant

Comment: Even after update - you don't invoke `objWithMethod.method` in your code.

Comment: @zerkms correct, i'm not actually calling it, i'm passing it as  a value (wrapped in an arrow function) into the method call in `y.anotherMethod()`

Comment: So? What is the problem then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117366/discussion-between-zerkms-and-derek).

Comment: The problem is no different from a call where the argument is a standard function expression, and not exactly specific to ES6 either.

Comment: `objWithMethod.method` is not called with the function, it's called with `x`. You probably want to test `.withArgs('some value')`, and your test will succeed when you change `anotherMethod` to call `func(x)` in its body.

Answer (score 0):

Loose matches you're trying to do can be done with [matchers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinon-match-api), to compare against any function it should be

```
mockObj.expects('method').withArgs(sinon.match.func)
```

And it will fail, because `objWithMethod.method` isn't called at all.

This

> // I want to test that `y.anotherMethod()` is called with
>
> // `(x) => objWithMethod.method(x)` as the argument

cannot be done, because the code wasn't written with tests in mind. JS can't reflect local variables, and `SUT` function is a blackbox.

In order to be reachable for tests and get 100% coverage, each and every variable and closure should be exposed to the outer world.